# Make the smith watermann algorithm run faster

Tags: python, algorithm

```
####make the BLOSUM matrix into a class for easier retrieval
class BLOSUM62():
    def __init__(self):
        with open('BLOSUM62.txt') as f1:
            entries = [(line.strip()).split() for line in f1.readlines()]
            self.scoring_matrix = {(entry[0],entry[1]):int(entry[2]) for entry in entries}

    def __getitem__(self, pair):
        return self.scoring_matrix[pair[0],pair[1]]

def local_alignment(v,w,scoring_matrix,gap_start, gap_extend):

    ###initialize the 3 matrices now 
    M = [[0 for j in xrange(len(w)+1)] for i in xrange(len(v)+1)]
    X = [[0 for j in xrange(len(w)+1)] for i in xrange(len(v)+1)]
    Y = [[0 for j in xrange(len(w)+1)] for i in xrange(len(v)+1)]
    back_track = [[0 for j in xrange(len(w)+1)] for i in xrange(len(v)+1)]


    ###initialize the maximum scores
    max_score = -1
    max_i, max_j = 0,0


    ###populate all three matrices 
    for i in xrange(1,(len(v)+1)):
        for j in xrange(1, (len(w)+1)):

            Y[i][j] = max([Y[i-1][j] - gap_extend, M[i-1][j] - gap_start])
            X[i][j] = max([X[i][j-1] - gap_extend, M[i][j-1] - gap_start])
            cur_scores = [Y[i][j], M[i-1][j-1]+scoring_matrix[v[i-1],w[j-1]], X[i][j],0]

            M[i][j] = max(cur_scores)
            back_track[i][j] = cur_scores.index(M[i][j])
            # print 'chose back_track value as'
            # print back_track[i][j]

            if M[i][j] > max_score:
                max_score = M[i][j]
                max_i, max_j = i, j

    print 'Finished making the matrix'
    # print 'M'
    # print M
    # print 'backtrack'
    # print back_track
    # Initialize the indices to start at the position of the high score.
    i, j = max_i, max_j

    # Initialize the aligned strings as the input strings up to the position of the high score.
    v_aligned, w_aligned = v[:i], w[:j]

    # Backtrack to start of the local alignment starting at the highest scoring cell.
    #while back_track[i][j] != 3 and i*j != 0 and i<=j:
    while back_track[i][j] != 3 and i*j != 0 and i>=j:
        if back_track[i][j] == 0:
            i -= 1
        elif back_track[i][j] == 1:
            i -= 1
            j -= 1
        elif back_track[i][j] == 2:
            j -= 1


    print 'finished backtracking'
    # Cut the strings at the ending point of the backtrack.
    v_aligned = v_aligned[i:]
    w_aligned = w_aligned[j:]


    return str(max_score), v_aligned, w_aligned


###now run the thing
#word1 = 'PLEASANTLY'
#word2 = 'MEANLY'

f1 = open('rosalind_laff.txt','r')
indata = f1.readlines()
f1.close()

###add '>' to last line 
indata.append('>')

word1 = ''
word2 = ''
linenum = 0
chunk = []
for line in indata:
    line = line.strip()
    linenum = linenum+1
    if line=='':
        pass
    else:
        if line[0]=='>' :
            if linenum==1:
                chunk = []
            elif linenum>1 and linenum!=len(indata):
                for i in range(0,len(chunk)):
                    word1 = word1+chunk[i]                  
                chunk = []

            else:
                for i in range(0,len(chunk)):
                    word2 = word2+chunk[i]

        else:
            chunk.append(line)

# word1 = 'PLEASANTLY'
# word2 = 'MEANLY'  

# Get the local alignment (given sigma = 11, epsilon = 1 in problem statement).
alignment = local_alignment(word1, word2, BLOSUM62(), 11, 1)

# Print and save the answer.
print '\n'.join(alignment)

f1 = open('out_localali_test.txt','w')
f1.write(str(alignment))
f1.close()
```

This is a working code of the smith watermann algorithm but this is too slow to run.Any suggestions to speed it up?
The main slow part is the backtrack part of it as its recursive.

What the Backtrack part does-
backtracking
looks in a matrix 
starting from i,j which are now the indices of the greatest score calculated 
itearting as i-1, j-1
until they find bbackstarck[i][j]==3
we check the value of backtrack[i][j[ recursively

Comment: What does this algorithm do? That will be helpful for figuring out ways to improve performance.

Comment: @OscarSmith this performs local sequence alignment

Comment: @OscarSmith Ill add more explanation to the part I think is slowing the code

Comment: You may be running into memory bottlenecks: [Hirschberg's](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirschberg%27s_algorithm) can be considered a memory conscious implementation of Needleman–Wunsch's.

Comment: (`bbackstarck` doesn't help my understanding.)(Look for implementations using NumPy.)